# Linq expression for altering array values

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

I have initialized an array of size `20` with a default value `0xFF` as follows:

```
Byte[] tempArray = Enumerable.Repeat((Byte)0xFF, 20).ToArray();
```

Now i want to alter the value at every 4th location to something else, say `0xA0`.

What should be the Linq expression for it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Enumerable.Range` and then project the index to the desired values based on the index:

```
Byte[] tempArray = Enumerable
  .Range(0, 20)
  .Select(i => i%4 != 0 ? (Byte) 0xFF : (Byte) 0xA0)
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: better `.Range(1, 20)`, otherwise the first byte is already counted as fourth

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Well, it depends on at which locations you want to have the value `0xA0` and how you prefer to write the `i%4 = ?` expression. Replacing `Range(0, 20)` with `Range(1, 20)` will produce different results.

Comment: @MartinLiversage could you please suggest some place where i could learn how to write lambda expressions and use Linq better?

Comment: @ankur: the best "place" is stackoverflow. Add LINQ to your favorite tags and follow new questions. Try to answer them with your knowledge and learn from better answers. You will be suprised how fast you'll learn LINQ. In general answering on SO is the best way to improve your skills.

Answer (score 3):

LINQ is intended for accessing data, not for making modifications to it. If you start with an array of 20 `0xFF`s, LINQ is not an appropriate API for making changes to it.

However, you can use LINQ to construct a new array based on the old one:

```
var res = tempArray.Select((v, i) => i % 4 != 0 ? v : (Byte)0xA0).ToArray();
```

This produces an entirely new array, rather than changing `tempArray` in place. You could make a copy of `res` into `tempArray`, or make an assignment if you want `tempArray` to change.

Comment: I assume that OP doesn't want to use or modify the old array but simply asks  what query he could use to get an array with alternating values.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I was going to suggest the same thing initially, but OP's use of "alter", both in the title and in the body of the question, suggests that he may want to make modifications to the original array. Of course it's hard to be 100% sure.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I was more interested in learning how to write a query like that. Whether or not to modify the original issue can be handled later. Thanks for the help. Also, could you suggest some place where i could learn how to write lambda expressions and use Linq better?

Comment: @ankur: the point is that you should never use LINQ to modify existing collections. You could create a new collection and assign that to that variable. That might work but it's a new collection and mostly less efficient than modifying an existing one.

Comment: @ankur I learned LINQ by reading the [pocket reference](http://www.amazon.com/LINQ-Pocket-Reference-OReilly-ebook/dp/B00CKYWZES). The book uses C# 3.5, but the concepts it explains remain the same in the current version of LINQ library.

Answer (score 1):

```
tempArray = tempArray.Select((b, i) => i % 4 == 0 ? (byte)0xA0 : b).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to create a new array with alternating values you have already nice working answers.

But no one showed the normal way to modify an existing array which is to use a for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.Length; i++)
    if ((i + 1) % 4 == 0)
        tempArray[i] = 0xA0;
```